# slack の投稿において利用できる markdown? の文法はありますか

Tags: slack

slack に自動投稿する bot を作っていました。 slack 投稿において利用可能な文法がどうなっているのか、知りたいと思いました。

#### 質問

- slack の投稿において利用できる文法がまとまった資料などはありますか?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 多くのユーザーの皆様より、Slack メッセージ内で Markdown を使いたいとのコメントをいただいていますが、現時点では
>   Markdown への対応は予定していません。

だそうです。
メッセージの書式に関しては[こちら](https://get.slack.help/hc/ja/articles/202288908-%E3%83%A1%E3%83%83%E3%82%BB%E3%83%BC%E3%82%B8%E3%81%AE%E6%9B%B8%E5%BC%8F%E8%A8%AD%E5%AE%9A#markdown-%E3%81%AB%E3%81%A4%E3%81%84%E3%81%A6%E3%83%92%E3%83%88%E3%82%B3%E3%83%88)から確認できます。(上記のメッセージもリンク先からコピーしました。)

Comment: メッセージがどうなるか　をオンラインでチェックすることもできるようです。
https://api.slack.com/docs/messages/builder?msg=%7B%22text%22%3A%22I%20am%20a%20test%20message%20~http%3A%2F%2Fslack.com~%22%2C%22attachments%22%3A%5B%7B%22text%22%3A%22And%20here%E2%80%99s%20an%20~attachment!~%22%7D%5D%7D